# Python: Unzipping and decompressing .Z files inside .zip

Tags: python

I am trying to unzip a Alpha.zip folder which contains a Beta directory which contains a Gamma Folder which contains a.Z, b.Z, c.Z, d.Z files. Using zip and 7-zip I was able to extract all a.D, b.D, c.D, d.D files stored within the .Z files.

I tried this in python using Import gzip and Import zlib.

```
import sys
import os
import getopt
import gzip
f = open('a.d.Z','r')
file_content = f.read()
f.close()
```

I keep getting all sorts of errors including: this is not a zip file, return codecs.charmap_encode(input self.errors encoding_map) 0. Any suggestions as to how to code this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually make use of a zip library of some kind. Right now you're importing `gzip`, but you're not doing anything with it. Try taking a look at the [`gzip` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip) and opening the file using that library.

```
gzip_file = gzip.open('a.d.Z') # use gzip.open instead of builtin open function
file_content = gzip_file.read()
```

Edit based on your comment: you can't just open all kinds of compressed files with any compression library. Since you have a `.Z` file, it's likely that you want to use [`zlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) rather than `gzip`, but since extensions are just conventions, only you know for sure what compression format your file is in. To use `zlib`, do something like this instead:

```
# Note: untested code ahead!
import zlib
with open('a.d.Z', 'rb') as f: # Notice that I open this in binary mode
    file_content = f.read() # Read the compressed binary data
    decompressed_content = zlib.decompress(file_content) # Decompress
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python33
    import sys
    import os
    import getopt
    import gzip
    f = gzip.open('a.d.Z')
    f_content = f.read()
 
Error I keep getting is
f_content = f.read()
File "C:\Python33\lib\gzip.py", line 360, in read self._read(readsize)

File "C:\Python33\lib\gzip.py", line 441, in _read
self._read_gzip_header()

File "C:\Python33\lib\gzip.py", line 290, in _read_gzip_header
raise IOError('Not a gzipped file')

OSError: Not a gzipped file

Comment: @DDS That looks like a pretty straightforward error message... the file you're trying to open isn't a gzip file. Do you know what protocol was used to compress it? `gzip` only works on gzip files. Since the extension is `.Z`, you probably want to use [`zlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html). You have to use the right decompression library for the particular file you have.