# Handling winrar archive files in python

Tags: python-3.x, compression, rar

I'm using Python 3.6 and I want to know if there is a way to handle winrar (.Z extension) files in Python. I have used the following code:

```
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile('POTCAR.z','r') #POTCAR.z is the winrar archive file
zip_ref.extract('folder to which I want to write')
zip_ref.close()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

What is the solution to this? Is there any other library for handling such files?

Comment: What kind of file is "POTCAR"? Is it a textfile? or a zipped image?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/18500083/8835357 , it has a neat description for gzip & zLib.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I have used [zLib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) for extracting winrar archives.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gzip:

```
gzip_file = gzip.open('Potcar.z') # use gzip.open instead of builtin open function
file_content = gzip_file.read()
```

and to save it (if it is a text file - since you didnt specify):

```
file = open(“my_file.txt”,”w”) 
file.write(file_content)
file.close()
```