# How to decompress .Z folder using Python?

Tags: python

I have over 150 folders with .Z extension and I want to extract files inside each of these folders. File names have the following format prcphq.099001.daily.txt.Z

Comment: Here you go. Use [ZLIB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18500083/12128167)

Comment: Here a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18500083/12396281) that explains how to solve your problem

Comment: @SergeyPryvala you're literally posting the same link as mine. Odd..